# Regex to split a user defined string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to split a user defined string which can look something like this

```
[test1]-[test2]>>[test3]Some Text:[test4]|test:[test199]|some_text:[test0][test100]
```

And at the end I want to get a list in js which looks like this

```
["[test1]", "-", "[test2]", ">>", "[test3]", "Some Text:", "[test4]", "|test:", "[test199]", "|some_text:", "[test0]", "[test100]"]
```

So I want the text to be splitted by the variables in the [] brackets and everything which is not in brackets.

The problem here is that I can only get a solution for everything which is in [] brackets or a more or less static solution.

Everything in [] brackets

```
(\[.*?\])
```

Not completely correct regex

```
((\[.*?\]))|([a-zA-Z0-9->:|_ ]*(?!\]))
```

This will for example not work with a text like this

```
[test100
```

Comment: Can there be nested brackets? If not, use `.split(/(\[[^\][]*])/).filter(Boolean)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it might be possible that there are brackets around brackets
e.g. [[test1]] the best solution would be ["[", "[test1]", "]"]

Comment: Then `(\[.*?\])` is not even partly working for you.

Comment: Yeah thats my problem my regex is only working for exactly this example :(

Comment: @str it was a mistake :( I edited it

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it looks like your first solution works for me. The result seems to be what I wanted. I will do some further testing.Thanks so far

Comment: The result ["[test1", "[test2]", "]>>", "[test3]"] is fine for me. Its something like I want as you can see in my first comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you do not care if there are nested brackets or not, you may use

```
s.split(/(\[[^\][]*])/).filter(Boolean)
```

The `(\[[^\][]*])` pattern matches and captures into Group 1 a `[`, then any 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` and then `]`, and uses it to split a string into chunks while saving both matched and non-matched chunks into the resulting array.

If there are adjoining chunks or it is at the start/end of the string there may appear empty items, and `.filter(Boolean)` gets rid of them.

See the JS demo:

```js
console.log(
    "[test1]-[test2]>>[test3]Some Text:[test4]|test:[test199]|some_text:[test0][test100]"
        .split(/(\[[^\][]*])/).filter(Boolean)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use positive lookarounds:

```js
str = "[test1]-[test2]>>[test3]Some Text:[test4]|test:[test199]|some_text:[test0][test100]"

console.log(str.split(/(?<=\])|(?=\[)/))
```

`(?<=\])`: positive lookbehind: search for a `]` before the split
`(?=\[)/)`: positive lookahead: search for a `[` after the split

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The result looks like what I need. I have accepted another solution as it was posted before yours. I will compare and see which one I will use.

Comment: Be aware that only Chrome supports lookbehind.